# Jupyter: Keyboard shortcut to move to the first cell of python notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

Is there a keyboard shortcut or function to view the top cell of the notebook. At the moment I can only find a functionality to scroll the selected cell to top, if so how can I select the top cell without scrolling up?
[image]

Comment: Would simply pressing 'Home' key work for you?

Comment: you could use `Esc + H` and go to `Edit Shortcuts` to see if there's such option.

Comment: @busybear Didn't occur to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Press `Shift + Home` to select the cells from current to first and move the cursor to the first cell.

You can also press `Shift + End` to select cells from current to last and move the cursor to the last cell.